# Find the density function of a distribution given its characteristic function

Tags: probability, complex-analysis

Let $\phi(t)=\frac{1-b}{1+a}\frac{1+ae^{-it}}{1-be^{it}}$ be the characteristic function of a distribution where $a,b\in (0,1)$. I want to find the density function $f$ of the distribution.

$f$ is the Fourier transform of $\phi$ by definition.$$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-
itx}\phi(t)dt$$

$$f(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-
itx}\frac{1-b}{1+a}\frac{1+ae^{-it}}{1-be^{it}}dt$$
It looks like I should use contour integral to find $f$ but I cannot locate the poles of the integrand and the contour integral really depends on the value of $x$.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: The characteristic function is the Fourier transform of the density, so the inverse Fourier transform maps the characteristic function back to the density.

You have to keep track of which version of the transform is used, but for characteristic functions the Fourier transform is the non-normalized version, so you have to use the appropriate scalar multiple of the inverse Fourier transform to get a density which integrates to 1.

Comment: Since $|\phi(2\pi n)|=1$, the distribution is discrete.